# Is there a way to open two window of VS code working for the same file that doesn't require overwriting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have dual monitor and I want to open the same file on VS code but don't want to show the overwrite message once I edited one of the window.

Is this possible?

Tried checking some of the threads but didn't answer my specific question.

Comment: cannot reproduce. I opened the file in two windows, edit one, save, and the change is reflected in the other without any warnings about overwriting. Did you try to make changes in both windows?

Comment: Yes, trying to make changes on both windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *edit* the file in two tabs at once

If you want the file to be syncronized between two windows, one of them MUST be is a saved (no changes) state (with a 'close' cross on the tab)

(you could *edit* file in to windows at once if https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/367 but it's not being developed  )